# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Routes' in '/codebuild/output/src806512313/src/src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

```
[Container] 2023/06/02 05:14:41 Running command npm run build

> creative-velzon-react@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Routes' in '/codebuild/output/src806512313/src/src'



[Container] 2023/06/02 05:14:43 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 1
[Container] 2023/06/02 05:14:43 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/06/02 05:14:43 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 1
```

When I run the AWS Codebuild process , I discovered that the Routes directory is located within the src/src directory instead of being directly under src. Consequently, I encounter the same error as shown in the picture.

And here's the buildspec.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
    commands:
      - npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - printenv > .env
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo $PWD
      - cd ..
      - echo $PWD
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - "./**/*"
```

And here's the App.js

```
import React from 'react';

//import Scss
import './assets/scss/themes.scss';

//import Route
import Route from './Routes';


function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I checked the EC2 server, I noticed that two folders had been created:  Routes directory and routes directory. However, when I pushed the files into the GitHub repository, I encountered an issue where the files were not located as intended within the Routes directory.

- build/src
  [image: build/src]
- build/src/Routes
  [image: build/src/Routes]
- build/src/routes
  [image: build/src/routes]

[image]

Comment: may be you need to navigate (import) right path of the Route in App.js

Comment: Some time it will raise because of cache...so clear cache

---> "npm cache clean --force"  
---> "rm -rf node_modules"  
---> "npm install"

Comment: I've attempted this, but it's still not functioning as expected.